# django freeze model

Tags: django, django-models

How to create a model with the following functionality:

1. Model shall contain a 'frozen' one-time boolean fuse, it starts as False, and can change to True, but only in one direction.
2. If the fuse is True, no changes to the instance should be possible.
3. The system should not affect the use of admin interface - if the fuse is blown (True), all writes should silently be ignored.

I'm running into a problem of how to check whether the database version of the instance contains blown fuse or not, for a given ORM instance.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `save` method of your model.

Comment: And do what with it? How can I distinguish whether **frozen** is True or False in the *database* at the time of saving (the state in memory **self.frozen** can be changed, and cannot be trusted)

Comment: Perhaps Model.objects.get(pk=self.pk).frozen? would that work?

Comment: @qdot Or, even better, put the frozen property in the query.

Comment: Is there any situation when doing a db query in save() results in integrity errors? related key saving, that sort of thing?

Comment: @qdot: I can't think of a reason why it would lead to a problem, but I wouldn't swear to its complete safety.